# JNI c to Java with a class

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have an .obj parser, code is:

```
class Model {
public:
    List *coords;
    List *tcoords;
    List *normals;
    List *faces;

    Model() {
        coords=new List();
        tcoords=new List();
        normals=new List();
        faces=new List();
    }

    ~Model() {
        delete(coords);
        delete(tcoords);
        delete(normals);
        delete(faces);
    }

};
```

this is a model file parser tool, which is parse a big file. The List is a linkedlist. (String array, char*)

How can I return this class to Java from C++? I know how can return a simple String Array with NewObjectArray, but what is the way to return a Class?

Thanks, 
Leslie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you create a peer class on the Java side that holds a pointer to the class in a long variable.

Jim S.

Comment: And you ensure that Java code does not use that pointer after the C++ class instance has been deleted -- for example, by managing the lifetime of the C++ class instance from the Java side (not through finalizers).

Answer (score 0):

In C++ code you can instantiate any Java object by calling env->NewObject() method and passing appropriate constructor signature to it. Constructors have special name `<init>`.